# When should I chose to upgrade to the Greater Vision Totem?

Tags: league-of-legends

**Greater Vision Totem (250g):**

> Places a Vision Ward (Pink Ward) that has infinite duration. (120 second cooldown). Limit 1 Vision Ward on the map per player.

**Greater Stealth Totem (250g):**

> Places an Stealth Ward (Green Ward) that lasts 180 seconds (60 second cooldown).
>   Store a charge every 60 seconds, up to 2 total. Limit 3 Stealth Wards on the map per player.

Is there any situation when I should chose the vision upgrade over the stealth upgrade?

Comment: When you are playing against Akali

Comment: @clcto oralces lens is far more better against akali.... you can still buy pink wards

Comment: I personally always take the vision totem. If I am playing a character like Lee Sin that can leap to an object such as a ward: Same answer, I use the  sight stone for normal wards.

Comment: I use greater vision when we have the advantage/map control since they are forced to play safe while the vision ward lasts longer.

Comment: @Randomizer can you explain this more detailed in an answer?

Comment: @DanceSC can you explain this more detailed in an answer?

Comment: @DropDeadSander woops I confused the vision one with detection* I always take detection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When should you update to a Greater Vision Totem? **Never!**

The Item right now is pretty lackluster compared to the Greater Stealth Totem and the Oracle's Lens. The trinket provides you with 1 Pink Ward every 120 seconds which is bound to a certain location. The other trinkets are a lot better in terms of utility.

The Greater Stealth Totem is basically a mini-sightstone (you can place multiple wards) and the Oracle's Lens gives your mobile champion True Sight for 10 seconds every 75 seconds.

Pink wards are extremely important during early and midgame but usually you just buy them with 100g left and If you place them smart they will make up for their gold in no time.

Go for Oracle's Lens if you're a Jungler or Supporter and take the Greater Stealth Totem on the Top and Midlaner. As an ADC you usually want to go for Farsight Orb to scout and prevent vision breaks. Obviously there are some exceptions to this but the Vision Totem should really never be bought in the current Meta.

Comment: I don't know, I find it pretty useful to secure baron, drake, or to siege. But I see your points.

Comment: @dyesdyes well....just buy a pink ward?

Comment: exactly my thoughts

Comment: every 6 minutes for drake, plus pretty often for baron? and in the meantime, it's also good to have a pink positioned in your jungle, or in theirs etc...
at the end, it will cost much more that 250 gold... Sure, if you are desperate for vision, then the pink ward is not the right choice, but if you have the advantage...